# Module 'moduleName' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or

Tags: angularjs

I am making a simple angular application (I have worked with angular a bit before), but I have encountered an error which I can't seem to get rid of. This is what the application is as of now -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="moduleName">
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Altigreen</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Where, my app.js is this -

```
angular.module('moduleName', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
      });
  }]);
```

And my home.html is just one line of text, so that's that. But I get this error everytime I try to load the page. It says failed to load module and displays a blank page. 
Help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: is that app.js complete? does that code get invoked?
try wrapping it to `(function(){ 
 your code 
 module definition
route definition
})();`

Comment: I honestly think it's something to do with the path. If I paste the app.js content inside a script tag in my index.html, it works as it should. I can't seem to fix this, however. @Nilesh